# Outputting non ASCII codes to a file

Tags: php, windows, character-encoding

I have a problem while writing non ASCII codes to a file with PHP.

For example when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> on my keyboard I get a  ¶ character.

But when I write [`chr(20)`](http://php.net/chr) to a file and after opening the file via Notepad++ it reads a DC4 or if I try to write it as a .csv and then open it with excel I get a ? surrounded by a square.

Comment: Different applications will interpret these controls characters correctly but may display different characters (as you are experiencing). The difference is not only with the application but also what fonts that you maybe using.

Comment: What is the problem that you want solved?

Comment: `Chr(20)` is Device Control 4 `(DC4)` in ASCII

Comment: yes exactly i have no problem in the interpretation , it's just displaying.

Comment: All these are correct but the first one. chr(20) is not ¶ but it is `DC4` (Device Control 4) and also � ([Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char//fffd/index.htm)).

Comment: well i know that if i type manually alt + 20 i will get the right display for it which is this ¶, so i was wondering why can't i do it with php !!!

Comment: Typing alt + 20 must not mean the same as chr(20). Which operating system are you using and which language setting, which keyboard layout and which character set for that input method where you press alt + 20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mainly misunderstand a feature of your operating system. As commented pressing that keyboard combo (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + *numpad* <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> ) does not enter US-ASCII character decimal 20. From the documentation of your operating system:

> If the first digit you type is any number from 1 through 9, the value is recognized as a code point in the system's OEM code page. The result differs depending on the Windows system language specified in Regional and Language Options in Control Panel. For example, if your system language is English (US), the code page is 437 (MS-DOS Latin US), so pressing ALT and then typing 163 on the numeric keypad produces ú (U+00FA, Latin lowercase letter U with acute). If your system language is Greek (OEM code page 737 MS-DOS Greek), the same sequence produces the Greek lowercase letter MU (U+03BC).

- *taken from: [To input characters that are not on your keyboard (Windows XP Professional Product Documentation)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/lang_char_code_input.mspx?mfr=true)*

From your description you've got [OEM 437 <sup>*Wikipedia Code page 437*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) so the codepoint you're looking for is the [*Pilcrow* <sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B6) and in Unicode this is [Unicode Character 'PILCROW SIGN' (U+00B6)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b6/index.htm).

So where-ever you want to output that, you need to find out the needed targets file character encoding and encode that character in the right encoding and that's all. No more magic, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff says, control characters (with ASCII code < 32) are always interpreted differently. For showing a paragraph sign, try sending either `chr(182)` or `utf8_encode(chr(182))`, depending on the charset of your target file.

Comment: you say (with ASCII code < 32) , then how come when i use ASCII codes > 32 i still have the same problem ?

Comment: it works if you use chr(182) on windows xp English (US) system